# Scraping this page with Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the tables that you get from this page after selecting a specific date (ex: jan 2015 to fev 2022) - http://vital.minambiente.gov.co/SILPA_UT_PRE/RUIA/ConsultarSancion.aspx?Ubic=ext

When I tried Selenium, I had trouble finding how to click on the pages (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) at the bottom so it would send me to the next table.

I'm trying this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'href="javascript:__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdSanciones\',\'Page$1\')"').click()
```

But I get an error: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdSanciones','Page$1')" because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

How would you do that?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any pagination there at all. Do you need to search first?

Comment: Yes!
When you define a start and end date("Fecha de Sancion") it gives you a table and pagination in the end with numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...etc)

Comment: You could simply do what Chris replied with grabbing the .GridPager a from there could do a while True: try: #loop through each by index except:break then click the ... tag. You could also find the total records /32 for page length.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty nasty attribute value to search on due to the nested quotes. It also looks like something that might change frequently.

A better approach might be to use CSS selectors. `.GridPager a` will select all of those links, for example. And if you keep track of the page you're on you can find the "next" page link based on that.

Beyond page 10 it mostly just loops, though there is an extra `...` link back that we need to account for. This is really a double pagination: pages 1 – 10, then pages 11 – 20, etc.

So something like this:

```
page = 1
offset = 0  # For the "..." back-a-page-of-pages link
navigation_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GridPager a")

for link in navigation_links:
    # Do whatever you want with the data on the current page

    # Next page
    navigation_links[(page % 10) - 1 + offset].click()

    page += 1
    offset = 1 if page > 10 else 0
```

Comment: @LuizFernandoToledo, please edit that into your question. Code is nearly impossible to read in comments, and with a language like Python where whitespace matters it really _can_ be impossible :-).

Comment: I tried this but it is not moving to the next pages. The only thing I added to your code was that Python should save the element with class "grilla" each time it moves to another page ('grilla' is the table). I tried to paste the code here but I don't know how to write code in a commentary. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.80)

Comment: Refind the navigation in the loop and access by index.

Comment: @LuizFernandoToledo, this isn't complete code. I don't even have Selenium set up. But it should give you a solid starting point.

Comment: Arundeep is correct, though. You'll have to re-apply the selector in the loop.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? Should I write the .click() again in the end of the loop?

Comment: I tried this and it worked! thanks for the support - https://github.com/luizftoledo/scraping-colombia-environmental-sanctions/blob/main/scraping_sanctions_colombia.ipynb